# ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed . I am working on object detection using tensorflow . Unable to solve the error

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, object-detection

I am working on object detection using tensorflow . I am trying to make my model detect the sign language using tensorflow using my webcam in Real Time . But the thing is that while running the program to real time detect the sign , I am getting the error.

This is the error  I am getting on the program .

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13712/1483899625.py in <module>
     18     image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
     19 
---> 20     viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
     21                 image_np_with_detections,
     22                 detections['detection_boxes'],

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py in visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(image, boxes, classes, scores, category_index, instance_masks, instance_boundaries, keypoints, keypoint_scores, keypoint_edges, track_ids, use_normalized_coordinates, max_boxes_to_draw, min_score_thresh, agnostic_mode, line_thickness, mask_alpha, groundtruth_box_visualization_color, skip_boxes, skip_scores, skip_labels, skip_track_ids)
   1248           alpha=1.0
   1249       )
-> 1250     draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(
   1251         image,
   1252         ymin,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py in draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(image, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, color, thickness, display_str_list, use_normalized_coordinates)
    158   
    159   image_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert('RGB')
--> 160   draw_bounding_box_on_image(image_pil, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, color,
    161                              thickness, display_str_list,
    162                              use_normalized_coordinates)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py in draw_bounding_box_on_image(image, ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax, color, thickness, display_str_list, use_normalized_coordinates)
    210               fill=color)
    211   try:
--> 212     font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 24)
    213   except IOError:
    214     font = ImageFont.load_default()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in truetype(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    853 
    854     try:
--> 855         return freetype(font)
    856     except OSError:
    857         if not isPath(font):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in freetype(font)
    850 
    851     def freetype(font):
--> 852         return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    853 
    854     try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in __init__(self, font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    185         if layout_engine not in (LAYOUT_BASIC, LAYOUT_RAQM):
    186             layout_engine = LAYOUT_BASIC
--> 187             if core.HAVE_RAQM:
    188                 layout_engine = LAYOUT_RAQM
    189         elif layout_engine == LAYOUT_RAQM and not core.HAVE_RAQM:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in __getattr__(self, id)
     42     # module placeholder
     43     def __getattr__(self, id):
---> 44         raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
     45 
     46 

ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

I have went through a some ways of solving this but none of them worked . Please help me with this error .

This is the code in my jupyter notebook  on anconda . I am not using any virtual env.
the code i am working on is of Nicholas Renotte and its repo is -> https://github.com/nicknochnack/RealTimeObjectDetection

```
# here are all the imports. 

import tensorflow as tf

WORKSPACE_PATH = 'Tensorflow/workspace'
SCRIPTS_PATH = 'Tensorflow/scripts'
APIMODEL_PATH = 'Tensorflow/models'
ANNOTATION_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/annotations'
IMAGE_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/images'
MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/models'
PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH = WORKSPACE_PATH+'/pre-trained-models'
CONFIG_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config'
CHECKPOINT_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/my_ssd_mobnet/'

labels = [{'name' : 'hello'    , 'id' : 1},
          {'name' : 'yes'      , 'id' : 2} ,
          {'name' : 'no'       , 'id' : 3} ,
          {'name' : 'thanks'   , 'id' : 4},
          {'name' : 'iloveyou' , 'id' : 5}
         ]

with open(ANNOTATION_PATH + '\label_map.pbtxt', 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}


!cd Tensorflow && git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models


CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME = 'my_ssd_mobnet' 

!mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\models\\'+CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME}

!copy {PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH+'/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config'} {MODEL_PATH+'/'+CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME}

import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format

CONFIG_PATH = MODEL_PATH+'/'+CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME+'/pipeline.config'

config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)

config

pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(CONFIG_PATH, "r") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    proto_str = f.read()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)  

pipeline_config.model.ssd.num_classes = 5
pipeline_config.train_config.batch_size = 4
pipeline_config.train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint = PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH+'/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0'
pipeline_config.train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint_type = "detection"
pipeline_config.train_input_reader.label_map_path= ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'
pipeline_config.train_input_reader.tf_record_input_reader.input_path[:] = [ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record']
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].label_map_path = ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[:] = [ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record']


config_text = text_format.MessageToString(pipeline_config)                                                                                                                                                                             
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(CONFIG_PATH, "wb") as f: 
    f.write(config_text)   

print("""python {}/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir={}/{} --pipeline_config_path={}/{}/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=10000""".format(APIMODEL_PATH, MODEL_PATH,CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME,MODEL_PATH,CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME))

import os
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_PATH, 'ckpt-6')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections

import cv2 
import numpy as np
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(ANNOTATION_PATH+'/label_map.pbtxt')


# Setup capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))


# till here above the code works fine and everything is working . 

while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    # integer type .
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.5,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        break
```

Also , I am  working on the code of Nicholas Renotte on his tutorial.ipynp jupyter notebook and the link for his repo is -> https://github.com/nicknochnack/RealTimeObjectDetection

Any help would be great .
Thanks .

Comment: Please click [edit] and put back the `import` statements which you have removed - this helps folk to see what modules you are using and how. Thank you.

Comment: Yes sir, I have made the imports which are there in the program. Also the code i am working on is of this repo -: https://github.com/nicknochnack/RealTimeObjectDetection . Please help me . I am on the last step to make this work . Just help me please.

Comment: Have you installed the *"freetype"* module?

Comment: I tried it installing in my my base python ( not in anaconda ) . It gives and error saying -: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement freetype (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for freetype"  Also when I installed it using conda . it gave error that no such package found with your requirement  name , like that

Comment: Yes the freetype module is installed now . after you said to install.  Earlier it gave error. But the program still gives error . Though I have installed freetype module . The program still gives error .

Comment: You may need to reinstall Pillow and maybe TensorFlow now that Freetype is installed.

Comment: Hello @MarkSetchell sir . I have left that project and I am starting from totally new step . I am using virutalenv also to make it totally isolated and making sure that all the things are working with proper steps and progressively . this time I will install freetype first , but I don't know how to install . because it gives error everytime when I write "pip install freetype" and I am unable to install it . Please help me how to install freetype . Is there any other command to install it .

Comment: Can you help me with one more error. I don't know why I am getting error and error . I have tried to solve it but nothing works . Please help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221089/unable-to-run-labelimg-py-file-for-object-detection-labelling .